# Does homology imply homotopy

Tags: complex-analysis

From complex analysis I know that for $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ and $\gamma$ in $\Omega$,
If $\gamma \sim 0 \Rightarrow \gamma \approx 0$ ,i.e Homotopy implies Homology.

My Question is, does the converse hold, i.e.

$\gamma \approx 0 \Rightarrow \gamma \sim 0$.

I would say no, because in the case there it would be true, there would be no reason for two different terms.
I have tried to find a counter example but I was not able to find one.

Does anyone know a counter example (or a proof, if $\gamma \approx 0 \Rightarrow \gamma \sim 0$ is true),of a curve $\gamma$, such that $n(\gamma;a)=0$ but $\gamma \not\sim 0$.

Definition:
Let $\Omega$ be a open and connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$. A cycle $\Gamma$ in $\Omega$ is called homologous to $0$, if $n(\gamma,a)=0$ for all $a \notin \Omega$.

Definition:
Let $\Omega$ be a domain in $\mathbb{C}$, $\gamma,\overline{\gamma}$ closed and piecewise differentiable curves in $\mathbb{C}$. We say $\gamma$ and $\overline{\gamma}$ are homotopic in $\Omega$, if there exists a continous map $\alpha:[0,1] \times [0,1] \rightarrow \Omega$, such that:

1. $\gamma(s)=\alpha(s,0)$ and $\overline{\gamma(s)}=\alpha(s,1)$
2. $\alpha(0,t)=\alpha(1,t)$ for every $t$ in $[0,1]$

Comment: Are you asking: a closed contour $\gamma$, is it nullhomotopic rel. endpoints iff. it is nullhomologous as a $1$-chain? Are you asking about homotopy / homology within the circle, or within all of $\Bbb C$?

Comment: I am trying to find a closed curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\gamma \approx 0$ but $\gamma \not \sim 0$. (I am sorry if I my formulations are imprecise, I am just now learning about those two topics and not really used to it/don't understand them fully).

Comment: No but homology and homotopy is all relative to some topological space. What's the ambient space here?

Comment: @FShrike I edited the Question to contain the definitions I use. The topological space should be $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: In the complement of two points, let $A$ be a loop circling one point and $B$ a loop circling the other. A loop implementing $ABA^{-1}B^{-1}$ is homologous to $0$ but not homotopic to $0$. (Didn't look at Chase's images, which come from google, so this example may duplicate what you already know.)

Comment: your definition of homologous is very unusual and not at all how the definition works in general. The answer by chase assumes the general definition via singular homology

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I am not really sure what you mean with $ABA^{-1}B^{-1}$. Do you mean with $AB$ to connect both loops which would look like similar to the infinity symbol. And by $A^{-1}$, doing the loop in the reverse direction?

Comment: When you said "for all $a\neq\Omega$", did you actually mean: "for all $a\in\Omega$"?

Comment: @FShrike looking what I have written down, it should be $\forall a \notin \Omega$, but maybe I made a mistake while writing.

Comment: You cannot beat something with nothing: you need to know a bit about fundamental groups of planar surfaces in order to understand Andrew's hint or any solution for this matter.

Comment: @Peter In John Conway's book "Functions of one complex Variable", in Chapter 6 there is an Exercise (Nr. 8) which is what I think you are looking for. There is also a picture of the curve.

Comment: @Philip I have looked at Conways book, and it is what I have searching for. Do you know a book where this is shown explicitly, since in this book it is an exercise. And I also am not sure how to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not. Consider [in this picture](https://images.app.goo.gl/zv6osVwhaFSYP45j7) the two curves on the genus 3 surface. They aren't homotopic but they are homologous because they bound a subsurface.

Edit: I just reread your comment and see you asked if nulhomologous implies nulhomotopic. The answer to that is also no: consider [the red curve](https://images.app.goo.gl/M6LKrF2rDBEsVYBz7) that separates the surface.

Comment: Thank you. Is there an example in $\mathbb{C}$. Because regarding homotopy and homology, I only know those terms from complex analysis. Visually it is obvious, but I would like to show it through calculation too.

Comment: Can you give the definitions you were given in class for homotopy and homology?

Comment: By the way, the phenomenon of nullhomologous != nullhomotopic only *sometimes* occurs. @Peter

Comment: Commenting here because I don't have the reputation to join the comments above. @Peter I believe you're correct in your interpretation of Andrew's answer. Something to think about re: the different between homology and homotopy is that order doesn't matter in homology (the $A^{-1}$ "undoes" the $A$, for example, even though there's a $B$ separating them) but it does in homotopy